# Xcode beginner (from Eclipse to Xcode)

Tags: eclipse, xcode

I want to learn Xcode in order to use its Obj-C, C, Java etc. project development facilities. I'm trying to start from the tasks I've done easily in Eclipse. For instance:
In Eclipse I used to create a new project and add a .java file with a main() whenever I wanted to test a snippet or a short algorithm that writes on standart output or console. I tried to create a java project in Xcode, but the templates given are ready-to-code complete mac apps, hence they are an overkill for a simple test. Starting out from an empty project, I began to notice that I had to write some shell scripts and some ant lines, also those codes had to be associated with "targets" and many other things that are not natural in Eclipse... It was overwhelming... so:

1. Does Xcode provide a simple solution like a Eclipse java project to aid those problems?
2. Where can I find (besides apple.com) an easy introduction to Xcode?
3. texeditor, java y javac are better options, and then is better to remain in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to Eclipse for Java applications, use XCode for Objective-C or otherwise native Mac OS X applications.

XCode is no match to Eclipse when it comes to Java support: there's no such thing as a Java project, ant isn't there, it knows nothing about JVMs (e.g. you cannot use JVM version X for project Y), there are virtually no plugins for XCode (things you take for granted in Eclipse such as the web services tools, tomcat integration, etc).

XCode is the ultimate tool for Mac OS X applications as it's very well integrated with Interface Builder, which you'd use to build and manage the graphical resources of your application. It does a great job at managing Objective-C and C code, recent version have built in static analysis and all versions are integrated with GDB (the C debugger).

Comment: As to question 2., the answer is: you can't. There are one or two books on Xcode out there and if you've been raised by a pack of C wolves, you might like them but as someone coming from the scripting side I can say from personal experience that you'll not find an easier (!=easy) introduction to Xcode than Apple's.